# Favorite Button in angular, after logout and login favorite product color is gone

Tags: angular, favicon, favorites

When click on favorite button, it will get favorite and when i unfavorite it will get unfavorite. But the problem is, if the product is favorite and logout and login. Then it will not show as favorite color but the functionality working fine. Only color is not working properly. For these everybody is saying,  The value of isFavorite will not persist throughout the lifetime of your application. Once this component is destroyed, isFavorite will be destroyed as well. Kindly help me regarding these

```
`Favorite.component.html`

`<button class="favouri" (click)="isFavoritee(x.ad_Id)"><i class="fa"
[ngClass]="{'fa-heart' : isFavorite[x.ad_Id], 'fa-heart-o': !isFavorite[x.ad_Id] }"></i></button>`

`Favorite.component.ts`

`isFavorite: boolean[]  = [];`

`isFavoritee(elem: any) {
    // this.toggle = !this.toggle;
    this.isFavorite[elem] = !this.isFavorite[elem];
    this.favouritedata = [];
    const favo = {
      'login_Id': this.localservice.getLoginId() ? this.localservice.getLoginId() : '',
      'ad_id' : elem ? elem : '',
      'category_Id' : 27,
      'mode': 'INSERT'
    };
    this.authservice.post('/api/Favourite/insert', favo).subscribe(data1 => {
      this.favouritedata = data1;
      console.log(this.favouritedata);
    }, error => {
      alert('something went wrong');
    });
  }`
```

Comment: `isFavorite` is a component level variable, so it is destroyed when the class is destroyed. You could store it in a service if you only need it for the life time of your application. If you need it when the user navigates away from the site, then using something like `localstorage` or an external database would be best.

Comment: If we store in localstorage, once after logout data will be gone know. I want to store for permanent. Is there any way I can store data for life time.

Comment: In external database we are saving, but I don't know how to get the stored values and assign to the product

Comment: It really depends on which database storage you're using. Some, like Firebase, have APIs that you can use to read data out directly from Angular. Others, like MySQL or MSSQL might require you to write an API (SOAP, REST, etc.) that does the data access for you when you make an HTTP request using something like `HttpClient` in Angular